# GridView doesn't show data

Tags: asp.net

my code is about search of Expression in Exp2 database and the result show in GridView
the problem is when i press search button the GridView didn't show
can you tell me why this happen?

```
protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI ; Initial Catalog=aspSPM_Exp2");
 string str = @"select * from [exp] where  (@search = Expression) Order by Expression";
 using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, conn))
 {
  com.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
  conn.Open();
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
  da.Fill(ds,"Expression");
  conn.Close();
  GridView1.DataSource = ds;
  GridView1.DataBind();
 }
}
```

Comment: Your query and latter code seems doubtful to me. What error/exception are you receiving when running this code ?

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement should be like this

```
string str = @"select * from [exp] where (Expression = @search) Order by Expression";
```

Currently what you pass as `Parameter` is considered as `Column` of `Table` and `Table` wouldn't have that `Column` so this will select no `data` and gridview will be empty.

Comment: Sorry ,but i didn't understand

Comment: what should i do  ?Can you explain more please

Comment: Simply replace your `string str` with my `string str`.

Comment: Are you getting data from `Database` in `DataSet` ?

Comment: when i used visual studio the code was fine but this happene after i upload file in aspspider.  Is there something that  i should added?

Comment: Run a profiler on SQL and check if data is returned or not ?

Comment: i upload database from sql server 2008 and not from vs 2013 .is this make  difference